# How to make a fork of module and use that from github repo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I wanted to make quick fix very fast related to https://github.com/handsontable/formula-parser.
Make a fork, committed my changes to develop branch, run `npm run build` to update the dist and added to my project.

`yarn add https://github.com/myname/formula-parser#develop`
But when i tried to use i got following issue `Cannot find module 'hot-formula-parser' from 'FormulaParser.ts'`
What i'm missing?

Ps: I know that best way to make pull request to origin repo, but i really wanted to test that very fast

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed to install the needed packages: running npm install or yarn install

try yarn add handsontable/formula-parser#develop

Comment: well, i just skip that details, without yarn install i won't be able to run yarn build, the problem is a way global, why after installing module from my repo, my project can't see that in node_modules

Comment: installing modules from github is a new feature in both yarn and npm as far as i know... it could be that your yarn version is old... anyway installing modules from github urls directly is not recommended ... this could break your code on CI/CD tools easily with you knowing why... you should install the package by the name and see if it works ( though even with the github url it should work)

Anyway i think the issue here is then with the format with your github url it should be like this username/repo#branch-name

Comment: after installing i can see the module in node_modules, so issue not in yarn

Comment: Installing modules from Github urls directly (via a package manager such as Yarn or NPM) is just as safe as installing a module from the NPM repository as both have equal chance to go unmaintained and cause unexpected errors, there is absolutely no different. That being said, when using NPM, risk may be increased when adding unverified packages as NPM allows execution of scripts during installation. Yarn does not.